# SVG file parsing issue in java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to parse the following svg file named 1.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="841.89px" height="595.28px" viewBox="0 0 841.89 595.28" enable-background="new 0 0 841.89 595.28" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_2">
</g>
<g id="Layer_1">
    <line fill="none" stroke="#ED1C24" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="103.667" y1="105.667" x2="126.667" y2="95"/>

</svg>
```

With the following java program.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse("1.svg");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I cannot understand I get

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1835)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:646)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1300)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1267)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1164)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:964)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:177)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

I tried to open the file with File class and it worked. Can you give me some help with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SVG file references a DTD which is getting loaded.

You can turn off DTD loading:

```
dbFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

and maybe also

```
dbFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
```